# Htaccess possible 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have a question about htaccess.

I have a url like this : 
http://www.asd.com/producten/kia?category=car

And I want this to be :
http://www.asd.com/producten/car/kia

Is that possible with htaccess?

I have tried different ways to solve it but so far no luck.

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^producten/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /producten/$2?category=$1 [NC]
```

AND

```
RewriteRule /producten/(.*)/(.*) /producten/$2?category=$1 [R]
```

Thanks in advance,

Mert

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Step 1: Redirect the old URI to the new one and prevent looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(producten)/([^/]+)/? /$1/%1/$2? [R=302,L,NE]

# Step 2: Internally rewrite the new URI to the old one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(producten)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$3?category=$2 [L,QSA]
```

If you would like to make the redirect permanent, change `R=302` to `R=301`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(producten)/([^?]+)\?category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(producten)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/$3?category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, thanks for your answer. It recreated the url that I want but now I am getting "page not found".

Comment: Oh you asked for 301 rule only. Check my updated answer for both sides of the rules now.